# Retrieve url with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, url, xpath

I want to retrieve with Selenium a full url, using part of it.

```
 <div class="productcarousel__mainitem slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 280px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00">
      <span class="productcarousel__fullscreen"></span>
             <img src="https://cloudxyd.com/image/.../gtfrgrfrtg.jpg">
  </div>
```

I tried this command without any success:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'url(//cloudxyd.com/image/')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting the xpath, you'll have to use `get_attribute('src')` on `links` to get the url

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'url(//cloudxyd.com/image/')]")
url=links.get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: @cruisepandey It's not, you just posted a few a mins before me, it showed the question 'unanswered' to me

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `css` selector.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".productcarousel__mainitem.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active img").get_attribute("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below xpath :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'productcarousel__mainitem')]/img
```

and get the URL like this :

```
img_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'productcarousel__mainitem')]/img
").get_attribute('src')
          print(img_url)
```

or if the above mentioned xpath highlights more than one entry in DOM, you could probably do something like this :

```
for img_url in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'productcarousel__mainitem')]/img") 
     print(img_url.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: Is there anything you are looking regarding this ticket ?